# Solutions of a special class of partial differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Consider the following equation:
$$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) + A f(x,y) + B\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y) + C\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f(x,y)+D\frac{\partial^3}{\partial y^3}f(x,y)=0$$
Where $A,B,C,D$ are some chosen real numbers. Let $a_k(x) = \frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}f(x,0)$, for $k=0,1,2,3$

> Solve this equation for $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

I was trying to apply Laplace transform for function $h_{x}(y) = f(x,y)$, but this gave me no result. However i would like to show you my attempt.

Consider function $F(x,s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y)e^{-sy}dy$.
Then i may rewrite the equation in following way:
$$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,s) + A F(x,s) + BsF(x,s)+Cs^2F(x,s)+Ds^3F(x,s)=H(s)$$ where $H(x,s)$ is some function that consists $a_k(x)$ multiplied by some powers of $s$.

I have noticed that this is ordinary differential equation.

Next, after solving this new equation, i would to use inverse Laplace transform.

But i don't know how to solve even this new equation.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are there are absolutely no constraints or initial conditions on this equation? It's very much like a higher order diffusion equation, so finding a general solution in terms of arbitrary functions doesn't sound possible. The Laplace transform also introduces several assumptions on the function. What is the ultimate goal here?

Comment: Without any additional constraint, there will be a lot of subcases to consider. Considering the case in which things are nice, this is actually a first-order ODE in $x$ so you can use the method of integrating factor (note that this is an ODE in $x$, so the term $A + Bs + Cs^2 + Ds^3$ is nothing but a constant; $H$ is also a constant as it only depends on $s$). Let $\alpha = A + Bs + Cs^2 + Ds^3$ and multiply $x^{\alpha -1}$ on both sides to obtain $$(x^\alpha F)' = H x^{\alpha - 1}.$$ 
Apply Laplace transform to initial conditions to obtain boundary conditions and solve this ODE directly.